# SDL2 begin_code.h file not found

Tags: c++, clang, sdl-2, coc.nvim

I just started exploring with SDL 2 recently and downloaded `libstl2-dev` on Linux (I'm using Mint, if that matters).

However, when I include the header `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`, vim keeps telling me an error `In included file: 'begin_code.h' file not [clang: pp_file_not_found]`, note that I'm using coc with vim.

I've done some research but I couldn't fix the problem. In particular, I noticed [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64187963/cannot-open-source-file-begin-code-h-dependency-of-sdl2-sdl-h), but the question was on VS code and I'm not sure how to apply this to vim.

Below is a part of my code.

```
#include "board.h"
#include <iostream>
#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL2/SDL_timer.h>

void Board::help_init();
```

Comment: `libstl2-dev`?  Did you mean [`libsdl2-dev`](https://community.linuxmint.com/software/view/libsdl2-dev)?

Comment: @genpfault yes sorry that was a typo

Comment: FWIW, Vim is not telling you anything, it's coc that does.

Answer (score 2):

Most Linux distros SDL development packages should include usable [pkg-config](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pkg-config) tooling that will allow you to query include and library locations/names that you can pass to the compiler:

```
g++ main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2`
```

(Or you can [use `$()` for subcommand capture](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4708549/44729) instead of backticks)

On this Debian box `pkg-config` returns these paths/flags:

```
$ pkg-config --cflags sdl2
-D_REENTRANT -I/usr/include/SDL2

$ pkg-config --libs sdl2
-lSDL2
```

Note that `-I` path means you should `#include <SDL.h>` & friends, not `#include <SDL2/SDL.h>`:

```
// wrong
//#include <SDL2/SDL.h>
//#include <SDL2/SDL_image.h>
//#include <SDL2/SDL_timer.h>
// right
#include <SDL.h>
#include <SDL_image.h>
#include <SDL_timer.h>
```

Though for whatever reason the Debian packaging for SDL add-on libraries like SDL-image have capitalized pkg-config package names:

```
g++ main.cpp `pkg-config --cflags --libs sdl2 SDL2_image`
```

Comment: Thank you, I was able to compile ```board.cpp``` using the additional flags. However, vim is still telling me the same error, and it's quite annoying. Can you elaborate on what you mean by #include <SDL.h> & friends?

Comment: Also, I don't know how relevant this is, but when I go to /usr/include/SDL2, I do see a file called ```begin_code.h```, and when I open it there is no error. However, when I open ```SDL.h```, the error occurred again.